# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

John Pitchers answered [Cant edit my module, blank page with a input select](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18930/120) (see below) but his answer was deleted by a moderator.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the answer (other than it being flagged because of it's length which doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad answer).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was the person (or one of the people) who voted to delete this.

Personally, I believe answers that require confirmation from the OP should be posted as a comment rather than an actual answer. More so in this case due to the length of the answer.

Perhaps this may seem a little harsh but it's normally the process I go by.

You are of course, quite within your right to vote to **undelete** :)

Comment: This seems to be common, maybe standard, in all the SE sites I'm familiar with. Been subjected to that myself, in critique even though not deleted. Part of the learning curve to join an established community.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't vote to delete this answer - or at least I can't recall myself doing so - but usually this type of short answers, where the half of the answer is a question to the OP look and fit better as a comment under the question rather as an answer.